# How to read multiple quadrature encoders using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupts, encoder, quadrature, mobile-robot

I am developing a 4-wheel mobile robot. Each motor has a quadrature encoder with 2000 pulses per revolution (PPR).

I have tried to read the encoders' pulses using an interrupt, but the counted values are not correct. Is there any way to read all four encoder at same time without losing counts?

Comment: What are you planning to use the encoder information for on the robot? Is this an indoor or outdoor robot? If you are planning to use it for odometry or even speed you might not want to use the encoders on drive wheels since drive wheels skid since torque is applied to those wheels. Odometry tends to more accurate on spring-loaded passive idler wheels which do not skid. You only need one for speed or two for direction. Which cuts down your encoders by half or 1/4 depending on what you are planning to use the data for.

Comment: Arduino due has 2 accessible encoders, stm32 parts have more, iirc they have 4. 2000 ppr is a lot of you're going to be running the motors at high rpm.

Comment: @DKNguyen it is an 4wd omni direction mobile robot. it is an indoor robot. i have using the encoder readings to compute odometry for SLAM

Comment: @FourierFlux encoder are attached at bare motor. After gear  reduction , motor speed is reduced to 200 rpm

Comment: Get a lower resolution encoder, you don't need 2000 ppr, external noise is going to dominate. Tbh encoders aren't really a good idea for slam long term since they have no way to recenter. They are about like an IMU. You're going to need either a camera or lidar sensor.

Comment: @FourierFlux He's probably stuck with the encoder he has. It probably came with his motor. Not only would he have to find another encoder made for his motor which is probably impossible unless it's from a company like Maxon in which case he would then have to pay through the nose for it. It's like asking someone to find another gearbox for their gearmotor.

Comment: Amazon sells encoders for 15$.

Comment: @FourierFlux That fit his motor? It's not availability that's the issue. It's finding one that fits. But if it is swappable than 8-count or even 4-count would be best. 2000 is wildly unnecessary on the wheel, let alone on a motor behind a gearbox. I still think it would be too much for the MCU though. Four 1000RPM motors with 8 count encoders is 533 interrupts per second, and the motor will probably spin several times faster than 1000RPM.

Comment: Assuming the shaft is exposed you can make a coupler.

Comment: An encoder on the wheel shaft would be best probably if he's getting his own encoder. An 16 count encoder on a wheel shaft should be doable. Four wheels spinning at 120RPM with 16 count encoders is only 128Hz. That would be doable in interrupts.

Comment: @Saravanakannan I've handled worse than this. If I read you right, you are saying "as much as" 200 RPM at 2000 PPR or about 6700 PPS per encoder. Since these are quadrature, that A+B. If you wire them up right, you can read all four at the same moment (one 8-bit port.) You'll need to set a sufficiently fast sampling rate to meet the needs. And I'd be writing this in assembly code. I might not use an Arduino, though. You could also consider dedicating four very cheap MCUs to this task (all coded the same) and let them talk to whatever software you write on another MCU. Lots of ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with Arduinos, there are some way to get better results (not sure if it will be enough to get no pulse losses at all) :

1. keep the interrupt routine as short as possible :

- Serial.print is strictly prohibited
- do not compute new velocity or position from within the interrupt : just update a counter (do the velocity/position computation from the main loop (or a low priority timer)). Floating point computation (even more so if using cos and sin) are very slow on arduino
- do NOT use digitalRead, read directly the port (ie register) : digitalRead does lots of "useless" tests, so it is quite slow

2. don't try to get all the information out of your signal (you can get 4 edges per pulse, one up and one down on each encoder channel), instead, look only at one type of edge (for example rising edge on channel A) : that way, you divide by 4 the number of interrupts (and you lose only resolution, not accuracy, regarding how much your wheel turned)
3. use a "powerful" arduino "compatible" board (for example an Arduino Due or Zero) :they are no longer based on the same micro-controler, but are still compatible with the Arduino environment and most libraries (nb : for direct port access, or other low level stuff, the way to do it will be different)
4. use several arduinos, on for each encoder (or pair of encoders), and let them communicate only the pulse counts to the "master" arduino that will use the results

PS : losing some pulses isn't a real issue on a wheeled robot, as the wheels will slip a bit anyway : the only important this is that you generate less error from missing pulses than from the slipping

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging do even one encoder in software and interrupts. Interrupts can only really handle the index pulse which occurs once per revolution.

With multiple encoders you basically need to use specialized encoder hardware. This could be using timer modules on the MCU which specifically have encoder modes or using dedicated ICs that do the counting and just make the count readily available for the MCU whenever it needs to read it.

Comment: Dear DKNguyen, Thank you for your reply. can you suggest any MCU with encoders modes. thanks

Comment: Parts recommendations are off topic here so you will have to search around. I can tell you that such dedicated encoder ICs are very specialized though and recommendations would become outdated even faster than normal (which is why parts recommendations are off topic questions here). They aren't used much so if you buy some, don't expect to be able to buy it again in a couple of years.

Comment: Most newer MCUs have timers that support encoders like those from Microchip, Atmel, or ST. You need to check the timer features in the datasheet. If an MCU is said to support motor control, that's a good sign it supports an encoder. But if you are using Arduino, be aware that it is a step up in complexity. It's good learning but be aware that it's a pretty big step. If you do not want to go on a massive tangent for your project, you might want to just get four small Arduinos and completely dedicate them to the task of counting one encoder.

Comment: @Saravanakannan The other way is an FPGA. That will support any number of encoders but is also a big learning curve (and expensive). If you are at the stage where you are using an Arduino, it is probably not a viable option.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I will try to do with newer MCU  which you suggested.

Comment: @Saravanakannan Four encoders is a lot for one MCU. Usually I think the maximum expected an an MCU is two. So if you do that, make sure to read the datasheet very carefully since not all timers on the MCU will support encoders and not all pins for a particular timer will support encoders. So you must check that there are four timer modules that support encoders, then check that the pins that do support encoders are all usable at the same time (sometimes they might share pins with each other or other critical functions that you need elsewhere).

Comment: I use ST but Microchip tends to have better encoder features (QEI). For one thing, ST encoder hardware does not have a hardware encoder indexing (at least on every one I have seen). You need to use interrupts for that. But Microchip does handle encoder indexes in hardware which could become important when you have four of them.

Comment: I'd go with DK and suggest an FPGA (small FPGA!) as a hardware encoder interface. Even the smallest commercial FPGA dev board will support 4 encoders with ease. It's such a straightforward thing to do though, are there any commercial solutions for this function?

Comment: @Neil_UK FPGAs are pretty great if you already have one and know how to configure one. After using an FPGA for encoders, it makes using encoder timer hardware on MCUs arduous because everything because the registers are so convoluted and the features so limited. But an FPGA is a big leap from an Arduino.

Comment: @Saravanakannan Moving from an Arduino to an FPGA board (a board or module, not a bare FPGA) is simpler in some ways compared to moving from an Arduino to a bare MCU. The MCU will require you to read carefully through the registers in the datasheet and set up the configuration code. The FPGA will require you to learn Verilog or VHDL but there's actually very little datasheet reading if you're working with a FPGA module/board. There are no registers you need to learn since you get to define everything. You really only need to decide what pins you want to use.

Comment: The OP attempting to learn vhdl is orders of magnitude more difficult than fixing his issue by either getting a more appropriate encoder or a correct MCU.

Comment: or using multiple arduinos...

Comment: @Saravanakannan, ignoring the "FPGA or not" debate, it's actually a "CPLD or not" debate. In simple terms, a CPLD is a smaller, very low cost, all-in-one-IC version of an FPGA. Don't consider an FPGA for such a small job.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward to handle encoders in your Arduino's software with no external interrupts.

Sample the encoder outputs using a regular timer interrupts. These interrupts are related to time and so can relate the changes in the encoder outputs to time, and thence to speed, very easily. The workload on your Arduino is relatively low.

Don't try to use the encoder outputs to generate interrupts through MCU pins. The interrupt service routines have to work backwards to relate their encoder output to the other encoder output, and relate that to time, to work out speed and direction.

This requires your RPM-to-CPU-clock ratio to be sufficiently large, which yours is, and for your CPU to have available computing time. Interrupts where no encoder changes happened will be quick to exit, keeping the load low.

The subject is expanded on in [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/599545) to a different question.